# Why does my voltage regulator always output maximum voltage?

Tags: ac, voltage-regulator, triac

I bought a cheap AC-AC voltage regulator from AliExpress (marked as being a 4000w SCR) very similar to the one toredown in [this article](https://goughlui.com/2020/09/19/quick-review-generic-4000w-scr-voltage-regulator-dimmer-motor-speed-controller/).

[image]

As one commenter points out, the output voltage remains at maximum, regardless of the position of the potentiometer (also that the input/output terminals are reversed). This is my 2nd one, I sent the 1st one back because I thought it was faulty - but this one’s exactly the same.

The OP replied that for triacs a load above a minimum must be connected for the output voltage to regulate, and that some meters do not measure true-RMS correctly (my first time hearing “triac” and “true-RMS”).

I want to use this to power an old XRocker gaming chair which requires 10v AC (the PSU is long out of production).

Here’s a very short video of my voltage regulator:

https://youtu.be/VHYtvK1arQ4

(The noise is from networking equipment nearby, not the voltage regulator).

When the voltage changes to/from 0v, this is because I’m switching off the input at the wall.

On mine the output terminals are on the left and the input terminals are on the right (N-Out, L-Out, L-In, N-In).

**How can I set the output voltage?** For obvious reasons I don’t want to connect it to my chair without limiting the voltage first.

If this device is unsuitable, what type of device should I be looking for instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you needed a 9VAC power supply, you should have just bought a 9VAC power supply, not this. It is unsuitable for outputing safely isolated 9VAC to your device. There is no need in your case to do any electrical work or repairs involving mains voltage or unsafe items bough dubious online stores. This is also not Aliexpress customer service.

And what you read is correct. That's a dimmer and it does not work or dim anything if there is no load so if you are measuring 230VAC on output that's normal - you don't have a load.

What you bought is basically a mains dimmer, it is sold as dimmer or motor speed controller.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I was hoping to have a variable voltage AC power supply for testing other random junk I pick up. I have a bench PSU for DC and I was looking for something similar for AC. Good idea for the chair though, I’ll check for a generic 10v AC-AC PSU online. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyBeckett If you want variable voltage AC, and you're fine with it just being at your local line frequency, what you need is called a variac.

Comment: @Hearth Nice, thank you!!

Comment: @DannyBeckett As you have been suggested a variac, please understand that they generally do not isolate the output from mains so while a variac does give you adjustable AC voltage, it may also be not what you want. Maybe combine a variac with an isolating transformer.

Answer (score 2):

This regulates nothing. It splits the mains AC sinewave voltage to shorter pulses which have reduced power to generate heat in resistors and light in lamps which are guaranteed to work with dimmers. Many lamps will not stand this type dimming. In addition some electric motors (the 150 year ago invented AC and DC capable motors with brushes only, not induction type nor modern brushless motors) can utilize this device as a coarse and load dependent speed controller. Never try to use it as a replacement for an AC output power supply which has certain output voltage. The pulses can be narrow but they may have much higher peak voltage than your equipment stand.

The device also connects your equipment galvanically to the mains AC which can be lethal for you or others if the equipment is designed to be fed from a transformer which isolates it. Get a transformer which outputs the wanted voltage and stands the load. Get a local qualified electrician to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the very poorly drawn schematic, you will see that there is a continuous current path through the circuit from line to neutral that is independent of the TRIAC.  This path has C1 and R3 in series.  At 50 Hz, the impedance of this path is 36.5 K ohms.  At 230 Vac, the current through the path is 6.3 mA.  This is more than enough for a meter or scope, with an input impedance of 1 M to 10 M, to see as full line voltage no matter with the adjustment pot and the TRIAC are doing.

Separate from that is another current path through R1 and R2.  The schematic probably is wrong in how it shows this part of the circuit. But whatever the circuit is, these resistors plus R4 and VR1 form another current path around the TRIAC.

As in the other answer, this is absolutely the wrong device to do what you want.  Also, it is not isolated from the mains, which makes it dangerous, and possibly lethal.

Here is the linked schematic for reference.

[image]